# xpath nontext element have value in condition

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

Is there a way how to detect that price is not text node? 
This code returns the second book, but I need to print error if the price is not a text node.

`xpath expression book[price > N]`

```
<book>
    <price>
        <nontext>value</nontext>
    </price>
</book>
<book>
    <price>
        N+1
    </price>
</book>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort of. You won't be able to throw your error from XPath, but you can check the type. `book[string(number(price))!= 'NaN']`

This will check for any books that have prices with child nodes: `//book/price[count(./*)>0]`
And this will give you results for prices with no child nodes: `//book/price[count(./*)=0]`

Comment: If you compare counts in XPath to 0, it's most probably unnecessary and more expensive (first construct result set, then actually count the values).

Answer (score 1):

To find books that contain child elements, use `//book[price/*]`. If you want those without, use `not(...)` to flip the predicate: `//book[not(price/*)]`.

These queries can be read as "all books, which do (not) have element nodes as children of price tags".